# C# workaround Autoscroll

Tags: c#, scroll, autoscroll

I've basically got a panel, where the user can scroll vertically. When s/he clicks on the button, I'd like to disable the Autoscroll, so the user can't scroll (a timer enables it back). Now, I want to programmatically scroll down, but with autoscroll set to false, it seems impossible. If Autoscroll is set to true, apparently I can't screw around with the panel's VerticalScroll.Visible and .Enabled property.

Does anyone know a workaround?
(I'm using Windows Forms)

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms?

Comment: I am using Windows Forms, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling scrolling for the user but not for your program requires surgery.  You'll have to intercept the user input.  Tricky to do because manipulating the scrollbars doesn't generate events other than Scroll.  But there's a backdoor, Windows asks what part of the window is being moused with the WM_NCHITTEST message.  That returns HTVSCROLL if the mouse is on the vertical scrollbar, HTHSCROLL for the horizontal scrollbar.  So what you can do is lie when you want the scrollbar to be unusable.

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox, replacing your existing panel.  Set the AutoScrollDisabled property to *true* when you want user scrolling to be disabled.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyPanel : Panel {
    public bool AutoScrollDisabled { get; set; }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
        const int HTCLIENT = 1;
        const int HTHSCROLL = 6;
        const int HTVSCROLL = 7;

        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && AutoScrollDisabled) {
            switch (m.Result.ToInt32()) {
                case HTHSCROLL:
                case HTVSCROLL: m.Result = new IntPtr(HTCLIENT); break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```